# Can I change the pattern of the confirmation-code in the password recovery email in IS WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using `WSO2 IS 5.9.0` and I want to change the pattern of the confirmation code that WSO2 IS send it when you try to recovery the password (`/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/recover-password`).

This code has the next format: `11ca0057-4111-4b88-1574-142ad65239kl`

I want the next format: `MXC231D`

Can I change the pattern of the confirmation-code in the password recovery email in IS WSO2?

If the response is "*Yes*", Where can I change it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not allowed to configure the code pattern for account recovery and confirmation flows.

It is generated [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/v1.3.15/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/recovery/password/NotificationPasswordRecoveryManager.java#L154) if you are planning to patch.